# Sharepoint Designer not opening HTML files

Tags: moss, sharepoint-designer

I have a FBA website and then I extended it (to use Windows Authentication) to be able to access it with Sharepoint Designer. It is MOSS 2007 BTW.

When I open the extended site with the designer, it shows the MOSS website hierarchy but doubleclicking a aspx or .master files it does nothing.

I can open it in notepad... but not in the Sharepoint Designer.

Any suggestion on what may be wrong with this website/ designer?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this a trial version of the SharePoint Designer?
It has happened that the trial version might not open the pages for you as [explained here](http://us1.trymicrosoftoffice.com/licensing.aspx?culture=en-US).

Otherwise, right-click on the page you wish to open and see/pick your option accordingly.

Comment: Thanks a lot... that was the problem. Just a call to Microsoft to activate my Sharepoint Designer and problem solved.